# Finding the length of first half of a string using string slicing in Python?

Tags: python

I'm working on an assignment in PyCharm, and have been tasked with the following problem:

> The len() function is used to count how many characters a string contains. Get the first half of the string storied in the variable 'phrase'.
>
> Note: Remember about type conversion.

Here's my code so far that it's given me:

```
phrase = """
It is a really long string
triple-quoted strings are used
to define multi-line strings
"""

first_half = len(phrase)
print(first_half)
```

I have no idea what to do. I need to use string slicing to find the first half of the string "phrase". Any help appreciated. I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: If I have a sandwich whose length is 12 inches and I slice away 6 inches, what do I have?

Comment: And what about strings with odd number of letters?

Comment: first_half = len(phrase)/2 to get the half length and I  think you are using python3 for which you have to use `//2` that is what they are  saying about type conversion

Comment: Make sure to add the line `phrase = phrase.replace("\n", "")` after you create the variable `phrase`

Answer (score 4):

Just slice the first half of the string, be sure to use `//` in the event that the string is of odd length like:

```
print phrase[:len(phrase) // 2] # notice the whitespace in your literal triple quote
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
first_half = len(phrase)
print(phrase[0:first_half/2])
```

It will need to be smarter to handle strings of odd length. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) for more on slicing.

Comment: For example, if the string is 5 characters you'll slice 2.5 characters in Python 3.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi how can you slice 2-1/2 characters?

Answer (score 1):

```
first_half = phrase[:len(phrase)//2] or phrase[:int(len(phrase)/2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note: Remember about type conversion.

In Python 2 the division will yield an int, however in Python 3 you want to use an int division like this `half = len(phrase) // 2`

Below is a Python 2 version

```
>>> half = len(phrase) / 2
>>> phrase[:half]
'\nIt is a really long string\ntriple-quoted st'
```

No need for the `0` in `phrase[0:half]`, `phrase[:half]` looks better :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this `print(string[:int(len(string)/2)])`

`len(string)/2` returns a decimal normally so that's why I used `int()`

Answer (score 0):

Use [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) and [bit shifting](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) (which will be faster should you have to do this many times):

```
>>> s = "This is a string with an arbitrary length"
>>> half = len(s) >> 1
>>> s[:half]
'This is a string wit'
>>> s[half:]
'h an arbitrary length'
```

Comment: I feel like this is really pointless. Shifting right is the same as dividing by two.

Comment: It gives you the same result but it does work faster. If the OP (or any future readers) need to perform an operation like this millions of times it will be faster than using division.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
phrase = """
It is a really long string
triple-quoted strings are used
to define multi-line strings
"""
first_half = phrase[0: len(phrase) // 2]
print(first_half)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply slicing a string using it's indexes.
For Example:

```
def first_half(str):
  return str[:len(str)/2]
```

The above function first_half accept a string and return it's half using slicing

Comment: Use `//` instead of `/` to get an integer